# How to easily compare length of more than 2 array arguments?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an object which has 4 array parameters that are all supposed to be the same length.

```
public Foo(
    int a,
    int b,
    type1[] arr1,
    type2[] arr2,
    type3[] arr3,
    type4[] arr4
    ){ /* ... */ }
```

I want to ensure that all of these arrays are the same length in the constructor, but I obviously can't do

```
if (!(arr1.Length == arr2.Length == arr3.Length == arr4.Length))
```

so I went with

```
if (!(arr1.Length == arr2.Length && arr2.Length == arr3.Length && 
      arr3.Length == arr4.Length))
```

but this isn't particularly appealing to look at, and wouldn't be so clear to change if I removed one of the arrays or something.

I figured there must be a nice way to use LINQ to do this on the collection of them, but my arrays are obviously not in an enumerable. Then I got creative (and probably silly) and figured I could initialize a hashset with the lengths and check if it's length is 1. Is there a standard / better way to check multiple array lengths for equality or is my `&&` method as good as I can get?

Comment: As you seem to have figured out, you would be hard pressed to find something better than your current `&&` approach. Sometimes, I like to separate the check into multiple negative ones on separate lines; `if (arr1.Length != arr2.Length) throw new Up(); if (arr2.Length != arr3.Length) throw new Up();` and so on.

Comment: How often are these arrays passed around together as a group? Are they always allocated together, etc? If so, have you considered hiding them inside a custom class?

Comment: Why are you passing related data around as distinct arrays and not just one collection of a class having 4 properties instead?

Comment: So far I think your solution is better than the answers...

Comment: Creating a hash set to compare 4 integers is a better solution than creating a custom class or just comparing them? @DannyChen

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  (and others) : Honestly not sure why I didn't think to package them together (probably because I couldn't conceptualize what the custom class would really be other than a struct for  convenience, (not native to c# and I struggle with that idea sometimes) but it makes sense to do so, that is what I am going to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about writing a helper method?

```
public static class Arrays
{
    public static bool AreAllTheSameLength(params Array[] arrays)
    {
        return arrays.All(a => a.Length == arrays[0].Length);
    }
}
```

Which you could call like so:

```
if (!Arrays.AreAllTheSameLength(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4))
{
    // Throw or whatever.
}
```

Or if you usually use the reversed boolean condition, it may be more readable to provide the opposite method:

```
public static class Arrays
{
    public static bool HaveDifferingLengths(params Array[] arrays)
    {
        return arrays.Any(a => a.Length != arrays[0].Length);
    }
}

...

if (Arrays.HaveDifferingLengths(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4))
{
    // Throw or whatever.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if all comply to the first one:

```
if ( new int[]{ arr2.Length
              , arr3.Length
              , arr4.Length
              }
              .Any(n => n != arr1.Length)
   )
```

Another (better) option would be to create a custom class, so you have one item for all types. Then you can simply create an array of your custom class: `CustomClass[]`. No need to check if they are passed in with equal length since the data type enforces that already.

Answer (score 1):

here is one approach with Linq

```
if (new []{arr1.Length, arr2.Length, arr3.Length, arr4.Length}.Distinct().Count() != 1)
```

Comment: Oh, indeed. Missed the `!`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have 4 types as type1 to type4. Now since you have to have equal lengths, consider the following:

```
public class Custom{

  public Custom(type1 t1, type2 t2, type3 t3, type4 t4){
      this.T1=t1;
      this.T2=t2;
      this.T3=t3;
      this.T4=t4;
  }

  public type1 T1 {get; set;}
  public type2 T2 {get; set;}
  public type3 T3 {get; set;}
  public type4 T4 {get; set;}
}
```

Now your Foo class can have constructor:

```
public Foo(
int a,
int b,
params Custom [] array)
{ /* ... */ }
```

The only Constructor of Custom class will make sure all type1 to 4 are initialised.
And array parameter in your Foo class will let you pass elements as many as you want. 
Overall effect will be all of type1 to 4 variables are equal in quantity across array of Custom class.

This is more like enforcing equal length rule indirectly rather than checking length.